# Outlook Calendar api Get future events

Tags: outlook, vsto, office365, outlook-restapi

I have this request and I get all the events:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events?$select=Subject,Start,End
```

**How do I get only future events?**

Apending "&start=2016-04-11T22:33:10" doesn't work. I tried '&$filter="start/datetime gt 2016-04-11T22:33:10" with proper escaping, doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting a calendar view:

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendarview?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}
```

Comment: In the end I did use your variant. First I had to loop thought all calendars with ".../Me/calendars" then I get all events starting from now with ".../Me/calendars/{calendar_id}/calendarview?startDateTime=..."